# How do I make my GridLayout clickable and will move to another activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am struggling to make my RecyclerView GridLayout for it move to another activity. I can't find a way to insert the setOnClickListener. Additionally, is it also possible to make the setOnClickListener if else? e.g if(...) setOnClickListener else if(...){}

This is my TrackActivity(or my MainActivity) below:

```
public class TrackActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TrackAdapter.ItemListener{

    RecyclerView makatiTrackRecyclerView;
    ArrayList arrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_makati_track);

        makatiTrackRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.makatiTrackGridView);
        arrayList = new ArrayList();
        arrayList.add(new TrackData("Latest News", R.drawable.icon_latest_news, "#64C0E2"));
        arrayList.add(new TrackData("Open Business", R.drawable.icon_open_business, "#9CD081"));
        arrayList.add(new TrackData("Voter's Info", R.drawable.icon_voters_info, "#F7B36A"));
        arrayList.add(new TrackData("City Officials", R.drawable.icon_city_officials, "#C78EF7"));
        arrayList.add(new TrackData("City Donation", R.drawable.icon_city_donation, "#FFACAC"));
        arrayList.add(new TrackData("Report", R.drawable.icon_report, "#E3D672"));

        TrackAdapter trackAdapter = new TrackAdapter(this, arrayList, this);
        makatiTrackRecyclerView.setAdapter(trackAdapter);

        GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        makatiTrackRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(TrackData data) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.text + " is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And here is my Adapter for my RecyclerView:

```
public class ReportAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReportAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList mValues;
    Context mContext;
    protected ItemListener2 mListener2;

    public ReportAdapter(Context context, ArrayList values,ItemListener2 itemListener2) {
        mValues = values;
        mContext = context;
        mListener2 = itemListener2;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView textView2;
        public ImageView imageView2;
        public RelativeLayout relativeLayout2;
        ReportData data2;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {

            super(v);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.makatiReportTextView);
            imageView2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.makatiReportImageView);
            relativeLayout2 = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.makatiReportRelativeLayout);

        }

        public void setData(ReportData data2) {
            this.data2 = data2;
            textView2.setText(data2.text2);
            imageView2.setImageResource(data2.icon2);
            relativeLayout2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(data2.gridBGColor2));
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mListener2 != null) {
                mListener2.onItemClick2(data2);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ReportAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.makati_recycler_grid_report, parent, false);
        return new ReportAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReportAdapter.ViewHolder Vholder2, int position) {
        if(Vholder2 instanceof ReportAdapter.ViewHolder){
            ((ReportAdapter.ViewHolder)Vholder2).setData((ReportData) mValues.get(position));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public interface ItemListener2 {
        void onItemClick2(ReportData data2);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to click the gridlayout and will redirect to another Activity. How do I do this?

Thank you for the time and answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the code and tested a demo based on the code(for simple, I changed some code), it worked for me.
If you want to move to another Activity, just added the code here:

```
public void onItemClick(TrackData data) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.text + " is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Open Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GridlayoutDetail.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

My test code is as below, the activity code:

```
public class TestGridlayout extends AppCompatActivity implements TrackAdapter.ItemListener2 {
    RecyclerView makatiTrackRecyclerView;
    ArrayList arrayList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_gridlayout);
        makatiTrackRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
        
        arrayList = new ArrayList();
        arrayList.add(new TrackData("Latest News", "123"));
        arrayList.add(new TrackData("Open Business", "1234"));
        arrayList.add(new TrackData("Voter's Info", "123456"));
        arrayList.add(new TrackData("City Officials", "1234567"));
        arrayList.add(new TrackData("City Donation", "1234567"));
        arrayList.add(new TrackData("Report", "12345678"));

        TrackAdapter trackAdapter = new TrackAdapter(this, arrayList, this);
        makatiTrackRecyclerView.setAdapter(trackAdapter);

        GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        makatiTrackRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick2(TrackData data2) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data2.name + " is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("TANCOLO", "===> data2.name = " + data2.name);
        // Open Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GridlayoutDetail.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

the activity_test_gridlayout is:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".recycleview.TestGridlayout">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The class TrackAdapter:

```
public class TrackAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TrackAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList mValues;
    Context mContext;
    protected ItemListener2 mListener2;
    
    public TrackAdapter(Context context, ArrayList values, ItemListener2 itemListener2) {
        mValues = values;
        mContext = context;
        mListener2 = itemListener2;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView name;
        public TextView id;
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;
        TrackData data2;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            name = v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
            id = v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_ID);
            linearLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.ll_container);
        }

        public void setData(TrackData data2) {
            this.data2 = data2;
            name.setText(data2.name);
            id.setText(data2.id);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mListener2 != null) {
                mListener2.onItemClick2(data2);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TrackAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_gridlayout, parent, false);
        return new TrackAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TrackAdapter.ViewHolder Vholder2, int position) {
        if(Vholder2 instanceof TrackAdapter.ViewHolder){
            ((TrackAdapter.ViewHolder)Vholder2).setData((TrackData) mValues.get(position));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public interface ItemListener2 {
        void onItemClick2(TrackData data2);
    }
}
```

The related to item_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ll_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:context=".recycleview.TestGridlayout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_avatar"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        tools:text="user name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_ID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        tools:text="12345678" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Regards the class GridlayoutDetail, just create an empty Activity for test.

If my code is not enough, you can debug your code by adding some log you wanted.

Comment: @zZealous12345 If you find it useful, could you vote for my answer? It is to give me greater encouragement, thanks.

Comment: I would if I can it says I need 15 more reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

change this in TrackActivity

```
public class TrackActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView makatiTrackRecyclerView;
ArrayList arrayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_makati_track);

    makatiTrackRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.makatiTrackGridView);
    arrayList = new ArrayList();
    arrayList.add(new TrackData("Latest News", R.drawable.icon_latest_news, "#64C0E2"));
    arrayList.add(new TrackData("Open Business", R.drawable.icon_open_business, "#9CD081"));
    arrayList.add(new TrackData("Voter's Info", R.drawable.icon_voters_info, "#F7B36A"));
    arrayList.add(new TrackData("City Officials", R.drawable.icon_city_officials, "#C78EF7"));
    arrayList.add(new TrackData("City Donation", R.drawable.icon_city_donation, "#FFACAC"));
    arrayList.add(new TrackData("Report", R.drawable.icon_report, "#E3D672"));

    TrackAdapter trackAdapter = new TrackAdapter(this, arrayList, this);
    makatiTrackRecyclerView.setAdapter(trackAdapter);

    GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    makatiTrackRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    makatiTrackRecyclerView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
         }
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        if (position == 0) {
          // Do action Here
        } else if (position == 1) {
          // Do action Here
        } else if (position == 2) {
         // Do action Here
        } else if (position == 3) {
         // Do action Here
        } else if (position == 4) {
         // Do action Here
        }else if (position == 5) {
         // Do action Here   
        }
    }
};
}
```

I hope thats work with your code, cheers